# Messed up newest kernel, how to fix it?

Tags: drivers, kernel

So I was doing the regular apt updates and decided to do a little clean-up on the *boot* partition. Anyway, during that "clean-up", I managed to mess up the newest kernel and now when I boot it, it seems that the only most basic drivers are working. The login screen loads up slowly, like it's printing from top to down, the laptop touchpad and wifi don't work, and the whole system is rather laggy.

Luckily, I had 2 older kernels up so I booted up from the GRU menu the second one where everything works perfectly fine.

I tried running the:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic`

(-46 being the latest), rebooted again but to no prevail. Still the same issue. I am not an expert Linux user so I really don't have any ideas what to do here.

That is, I can only assume it's only the kernel.

These are the images I have on my system:

```
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-52-generic              5.13.0-52.59~20.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-41-generic              5.15.0-41.44~20.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic              5.15.0-43.46~20.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic              5.15.0-46.49~20.04.1                        amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ri  linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-46-generic     5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-52-generic     5.13.0-52.59~20.04.1                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-43-generic     5.15.0-43.46~20.04.1                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Also, what's the difference between the *linux-image* and *linux-image-unsigned* ?

It's not that I don't want to troubleshot this myself, as most of us like it. But I am kinda limited with my time right now and I am a bit scared to mess with kernels as it could mess up my boot to the point I can't use the system.

edit: I was thinking of upgrading to 22.04 LTS, where I have 2 questions regarding that idea:

- will that fix my issue?
- regarding the same issue, will this upgrade make things worse?

Comment: actually ```5.15.0-47``` is the newest kernel version available.

Comment: It's not offering it when I run the *sudo apt update* command. Should I just upgrade it manually?

Comment: apparently unsigned images do not support "secure boot" and should be the same thing other than that, but some people have reported them having bad performance. you can download 5.15.0-47 linux-image linux-headers linux-modules .deb packages and install them with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` . can you try `sudo update-grub` and see if it helps? also maybe post `dmesg` output, there might be some hints

Comment: Try kernel 5.17.0-1016-oem, it is also the newest one.

Comment: @Petar Yes, you can install it manually, but there is a script which makes it easier.
https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
once you follow the install instructions, do ```ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -i 5.15```.
Plus the script installs a much more stable kernel.

Comment: @Cagri I did try updating grub, same result nonetheless. I'll try the manual install, let you all know how it goes.

Comment: A'ight, I've managed to upgrade the kernel and booted it up no issues whatsoever. However, I am having certain purge issues. Not sure if I should stack it here or post a new question. The \boot partition is pretty much filled up from all this gameplay. And `sudo apt autoremove` didn't help at all. I also tried manually removing old kernels with the `sudo apt remove linux-image-xxx` which only created a new image with the same version. Oh, and I tried the script suggested by @RishonJR , it lists properly but I get the "Could not create build" error. I am thinking of going nuclear here...

Comment: do they show as installed (ii) on dpkg? if not, maybe just delete the unused kernels with `rm`? - btw just saw your edit, 5.15.0-47 is available on 22.04 LTS, probably not on your older version, that's why you weren't able to install it with apt